# Velocity Template auto-reload doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, macros, velocity

I want to reload velocity template as it's changed. For this I've set the followings, but reload doesn't work when I manually change a .vm file inside `META-INF/template/` .

```
velocimacro.library.autoreload = true
[spring|file|class].resource.loader.cache = false
```

Any idea? Here is my velocityEngine bean

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="classpath:META-INF/template/" />
    <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="false" />
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="spring.resource.loader.cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="class.resource.loader.cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="velocimacro.library.autoreload">true</prop>

            <prop key="resource.loader">spring</prop>
            <prop key="directive.foreach.counter.name">counter</prop>
            <prop key="directive.foreach.counter.initial.value">0</prop>
            <prop key="spring.resource.loader.class">
                org.springframework.ui.velocity.SpringResourceLoader
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `setResourceLoaderPath` [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.3/api/org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory.html#setResourceLoaderPath%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> Note that resource caching will be enabled in any case. With the file resource loader, the last-modified timestamp will be checked on access to detect changes. **With SpringResourceLoader, the resource will be cached forever (for example for class path resources).**
>
> ...
>
> To enforce the use of SpringResourceLoader, i.e. to not resolve a path as file system resource in any case, turn off the "preferFileSystemAccess" flag. See the latter's javadoc for details.

Then for `setPreferFileSystemAccess`

> Set whether to prefer file system access for template loading. **File system access enables hot detection of template changes.**
>
> If this is enabled, VelocityEngineFactory will try to resolve the specified "resourceLoaderPath" as file system resource (which will work for expanded class path resources and ServletContext resources too).
>
> Default is "true". **Turn this off to always load via SpringResourceLoader (i.e. as stream, without hot detection of template changes)**, which might be necessary if some of your templates reside in an expanded classes directory while others reside in jar files.

So looks like there are a few things that contribute to the problem. Using `SpringResourceLoader` with `classpath:` pseudo-protocol makes Spring cache the template infinitely. On top of that `preferFileSystemAccess` is disabled which makes sure that template is never accessed through the file system.

Comment: Yes, it seems that SpringResourceLoader always caches. I was only able to turn off caching by using another resource loader such as org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this property resolved this issue for me:

```
velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline.to.replace.global=true
```

I had the same problem when using the properties below but adding the above property enabled me to get auto-reload to work:

```
velocimacro.library.autoreload=true
file.resource.loader.cache=false
```

Please see [How to edit a velocimacro without restarting velocity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567742/how-to-edit-a-velocimacro-without-restarting-velocity)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i have velocityEngine bean set  like this:

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/templates/"/>
        <property name="velocityProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="input.encoding">utf-8</prop>
             </props>
        </property>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="false"/>
        <property name="prefix" value=""/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml"/>
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

(Assuming you use Spring framework, by the way)
and I have no problems with caching whatsoever. But I use the configurer bean instead of beanfactory. Try look into this.

And there's the thing, it's trivial, but still..., do you actually redeploy your project after modifying the template?

Comment: I don't use velocity as view generator. This is just used as template engine to some text content generation. Yes, as I checked the file is automatically redeployed to tomcat and should be visible to the application server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in the past, so I've written this blog entry: [Spring-mvc + Velocity + DCEVM](http://blog.rafaelsanches.com/2012/02/02/spring-mvc-velocity-dcevm/)

The principal idea is to use this at least at development time:

```
webapp.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader
webapp.resource.loader.path = /WEB-INF/views/
webapp.resource.loader.cache = true
webapp.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval = 2
```

I've found that it works better than the SpringResourceLoader because now in my templates I can have includes like these:

```
#parse("/parts/header.vm")
```

Where the path of the header is in /WEB-INF/views/header.vm