# Changes to init_custom.vm not showing up

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

I'm building a new Liferay theme and being crushed by this problem.

When I make changes to the `init_custom.vm`, the only possible way for me to see the changes is to restart Tomcat. When I make other changes to my theme, such as editing my CSS or adding images, I can see the changes after deploying the theme via the Ant Deploy target. No such luck with the templates.

I checked the `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/my-theme/init_custom.vm` after deploying, and that file does reflect my changes.

I cannot continue to develop if this is going to be the cycle. I must be able to make changes to the velocity template without requiring a restart. Any suggestions?

I'm using the Eclipse Liferay IDE and the Ant build to deploy my theme when I make changes. I'm using the Liferay 6.0.6 Tomcat bundle. I've also already added `include-and-override=portal-developer.properties` to my `portal-ide.properties` file.

Thanks!!!

(also asked this in the Liferay Forums, and I'll make sure to copy back any answers I get: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11292911)

Comment: FYI: I've seen
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567742/how-to-edit-a-velocimacro-without-restarting-velocity
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298396/velocity-template-auto-reload-doesnt-work
and they did not work for me.

Upgrading to 6.1 beta did, for some reason, work.

Comment: I switched to the 6.1 Beta and do not have the problem on that release, so it was just with 6.0.6...

Comment: So if I may request, can you answer your own question and accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to the 6.1 Beta and do not have the problem on that release, so it was just with 6.0.6.

Also: I've seen [How to edit a velocimacro without restarting velocity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567742/how-to-edit-a-velocimacro-without-restarting-velocity) and [Testing JSON API in Rails 3.2 using rspec using exact PUT/POST bodies as Backbone would send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497897/testing-json-api-in-rails-3-2-using-rspec-using-exact-put-post-bodies-as-backbon) and they did not work for me. Upgrading to 6.1 beta did, for some reason, work.

Answer (score 1):

Liferay also caches everything Velocity related which sometimes can present itself in the way you describe: changes to templates don't seem to show unless you restart Liferay. You can turn off this behavior if you set the following property in your portal-ext.properties file:

```
velocity.engine.resource.manager.cache.enabled=false
```